# Fetching data with redux doesn't work for me, initialState don't change

Tags: react-native, redux, fetch-api, form-data

I started my RN project without redux and when I fetch data (using formData) it works fine without redux, but I've decided to inculude Redux in my project. that's what I did:

I created two new folder , one for actions (constants and ations files) and the other for store witch contains a folder for reducer

[image]

after that I created 3 actions like this: getScoreList, getScoreListSuccess, getScoreListFailure

```
function getScoreListSuccess(data) {
  return {
    type: FETCHING_SCORE_LIST_SUCCESS,
    data: data
  }
}
```

in the same file I created function for fetching data using async await and formData:

```
import FormData from 'FormData';

const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('userId', '1');
formData.append('key', 'XXXXXXXXX');

export const getScoreFromAPI = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
     dispatch(getScoreList());
     try {
       let res = await fetch('https://www.***.com/***/***/***.php', {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
         },
         body: formData,
       })
       let json = await res.json();
       dispatch(getScoreListSuccess(json));
     } catch (err) {
       console.log("the error is:  " + error)
     }
   };
};
```

Then I set my reducer for 3 cases:

```
import {FETCHING_SCORE_LIST, FETCHING_SCORE_LIST_SUCCESS, FETCHING_SCORE_LIST_FAILURE} from '../../actions/constants'

const initialState = {
  scoreList: [],
  isFetching: false,
  error: false,
}

export default function getScoreList(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCHING_SCORE_LIST:
      return {
         ...state,
         isFetching: true,
         scoreList: [],
      };

    case FETCHING_SCORE_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return {
         ...state,
         isFetching: false,
         scoreList: action.data,
      };

    case FETCHING_SCORE_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return {
         ...state,
         isFetching: false,
         error: true,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and in another file (index.js) that's what I did:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import getScoreList from './scoreListReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  getScoreListS: getScoreList,
})
export default rootReducer
```

then I created my store with thunk middleware in configStore.js file

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import rootReducer from './Reducers/index'

export default function configureStore() {
  let store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
  return store
}
```

app.js file:

```
...
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import rootReducer from './Store/Reducers/index'

const createStoreWithMW = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMW(rootReducer);

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Navigation/>
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

And finally I connected my component with redux :

```
...
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {getScoreFromAPI} from '../../actions/actions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
...
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return{
    scoreListState: state.getScoreListS,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
    fetchScoreList: getScoreFromAPI
}, dispatch)

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(ScoreList);
```

to test it I console.warn scoreListState:

```
  componentDidMount() {
  console.warn(this.props.scoreListState);
  }
```

this is what I have

[image]

I hope it was clear enough even if it's a little bit long

Comment: I guess the problem is you have not called fetchScoreList in your component. check the bindActionCreater

Comment: I dont understand, you mean I have to set fetchScoreList: getScoreFromAPI() instead of fetchScoreList: getScoreFromAPI ? I just try it now with () and nothing change

Comment: no one can help ?